# After Enable adoptable storage in my Root Galaxy ... play Store Cant Update Any App

Tags: root-access, adoptable-storage

i root my Device (A320F)(Galaxy A3 2017)
and after that enable adoptable storage via TWRP zip installer package ...
every things is OK and with Titanium Backup Move All my app To adoptable storage ...

but now when i want to Update my app via play Store give me Error

[image]

and this is Full LogCat of Finsky : [Download](https://file.io/wC8sO123pyAD)

i thinks interest line in log is

```
07-22 11:07:16.405 31501 31710 E Finsky  : java.io.IOException: Cannot automatically move com.alopeyk.customer from decf87e0-1c08-4b00-8cee-3a4d11ad36cc to internal storage
```

and with Install with adb from my PC this is Error :

[image]

and this is what happen when i try update any apps ..

**I think if i fix mount point SD card address issue will be fixed but how ? please help**

[image]

this is mount point in my device

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so har? Clear PlayStore app cache, reboot device, ... How old is the sd-card and has it been used before (the question is: is it a genuine or a fake sd-card?)

Comment: @Robert Reboot and clear cache ... my SD card is genuine and fast but Samsung Block adoptable storage for all SD card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check that on developer menu and all issue fixed